# Splitting string into parts with regex in Dart

Tags: dart

If i have some test data john_doe01.jpg how can i use regex or something else to split this into separate strings like..

john_doe or john and doe
01
jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a RegExp using the constructor, like: `var re = RegExp(r"\d+|[a-zA-Z]+");`.

You can get the substrings matching the RegExp as: `var matches = [...re.allMatches(myText)];`

In your case, `var myText = "john_doe01.jpg";`, that would give you the result `['john", "doe", "01", "jpg"]`.
If that's not what you want, you'll have to fiddle with the RegExp until it gives you what you do want. It usually helps writing down in prose, and in excruciating detail, what it is you want, and then writing the RegExp afterwards.